# Positioning objects in Swing Card layout

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a Card layout with Swing. One of my cards has:

```
 Panel p3 = new Panel();
 p3.add(new Label("HELLO"));
 p3.add(new Button("MyButton"));
```

Which looks fine. However, I would now like to add a further label/button just below, but if I try:

```
 p3.add(new Label("HELLOTWO"));
 p3.add(new Button("MyButtonTWO"));
```

These will be positioned horizontally rather than vertically, any suggestions as to how I can obviate to such problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No, whatever you are saying should not happen. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Sage `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, so components will be laid out horizontally next to each other...or did I mis read this...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, look at the title ;)

Comment: @Sage Look at `p3`...;) ... *"One of my cards has..."* - Misleading (I hope :P)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, look at initializing class: `Panel()` :P. Yup complete misleading

Comment: @Sage Still good to look for clarification...just freaked me out that's all :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `JPanel` is using a `FlowLayout`, which will, as the name suggestions, flow components one after the other.

Without adding additional 3rd party libraries, the best choice might be to use `GridBagLayout`.  Be wared, `GridBagLayout` is among the most powerful and complex layout managers available in core Swing API

Take a look at [Laying out components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details about how to use layout managers